I can't get the program to see my override buttons
I want to be able to press the buttons on the web app to change the lights, but I also want to be able to override the web app with physical buttons to change the LEDs like the web app can. This is a prototype for a wireless pool pump controller I'm making for my dad. I'm using a PICO w with micropython.
I tried putting the button's code above all the network stuff with a while true loop and that didn't let me connect to the network, I tried just an or with the requests for example if request == '/low?' or lowButton.value() == 0: but that would only read the button when I interacted with the web app and I want the button to work on its own. Furthermore, I tried making the "if button pressed do this" part a function and then address the function in the "try" code at the very end and I got the same result. It just seems like nothing is working
import network
import socket
from time import sleep
from machine import Pin
import machine
import utime

ssid = 'ssid'
password = 'password'

lowTime = 5 #when the pump kicks on low speed
highTime = 22 #when the pump kicks on high speed

lowSpeed = Pin(0, Pin.OUT) #the pins for the contactors right now they are just leds
highSpeed = Pin(1, Pin.OUT)

lowButton = Pin(6, Pin.IN, Pin.PULL_UP) #the overide switches
highButton = Pin(7, Pin.IN, Pin.PULL_UP)
offButton = Pin(8, Pin.IN, Pin.PULL_UP)
timeButton = Pin(9, Pin.IN, Pin.PULL_UP) #the same as schedule

lowLed = Pin(10, Pin.OUT) #the status lights for each mode
highLed = Pin(11, Pin.OUT)
offLed = Pin(12, Pin.OUT)
timeLed = Pin(13, Pin.OUT)
#I got the networking code from a raspberry pi pico w networking tutorial
def connect():
    wlan = network.WLAN(network.STA_IF)
    wlan.active(True)
    wlan.connect(ssid, password)
    while wlan.isconnected() == False:
        print('Waiting for connection...')
        sleep(1)
    ip = wlan.ifconfig()[0]
    print(f'Connected on {ip}')
    return ip
def open_socket(ip):
    address = (ip, 80)
    connection = socket.socket()
    connection.bind(address)
    connection.listen(1)
    return connection
    
def webpage():
    html = f"""
             <!DOCTYPE html>
                <html>
                    <head>
                        <meta charset="UTF-8">
                        <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
                    </head>
                    <body style="background-color: black; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; line-height: 100px;">
                        <h1 style="color:aliceblue; font-size: 300%;">
                            Father's Pool Pump Controll (PPC)
                        </h1>
                        <form action="./low">
                            <input type="submit" value="Low" style="height:350px; width:600px; border-radius: 40px; font-size:xx-large; background-color: rgb(0, 123, 254); color: aliceblue; font-weight: bold; border-color: aliceblue;"/>
                        </form>
                        <form action="./high">
                            <input type="submit" value="High" style="height:350px; width:600px; border-radius: 40px; font-size:xx-large; background-color: rgb(0, 123, 254); color: aliceblue; font-weight: bold; border-color: aliceblue;"/>
                        </form>
                        <form action="./off">
                            <input type="submit" value="OFF" style="height:350px; width:600px; border-radius: 40px; font-size:xx-large; background-color: rgb(0, 123, 254); color: aliceblue; font-weight: bold; border-color: aliceblue;"/>
                        </form>
                        <form action="./schedule">
                            <input type="submit" value="Schedule" style="height:350px; width:600px; border-radius: 40px; font-size:xx-large; background-color: rgb(0, 123, 254); color: aliceblue; font-weight: bold; border-color: aliceblue;"/>
                        </form>
                    </body>
                </html>
            """
    return str(html)
def serve(connection):
    while True:
        client = connection.accept()[0]
        request = client.recv(1024)
        request = str(request)
        try:
            request = request.split()[1]
        except IndexError:
            pass
        if request == '/low?':
            lowSpeed.on()
            highSpeed.off()
            print("Low Selected!!!")
            lowLed.value(1)
            highLed.value(0)
            offLed.value(0)
            timeLed.value(0)
        if request == '/high?':
            lowSpeed.off()
            highSpeed.on()
            print("High Selected!!!")
            lowLed.value(0)
            highLed.value(1)
            offLed.value(0)
            timeLed.value(0)
        if request == '/off?':
            lowSpeed.off()
            highSpeed.off()
            print("Off Selected!!!")
            lowLed.value(0)
            highLed.value(0)
            offLed.value(1)
            timeLed.value(0)
        if request == '/schedule?':
            print("Schedule Seleceted!!!")
            if utime.localtime()[3] >= highTime or utime.localtime()[3] < lowTime:
                lowSpeed.off()
                highSpeed.on()
                print("Switching to High!!!")
            if utime.localtime()[3] >= lowTime or utime.localtime()[3] < highTime:
                lowSpeed.on()
                highSpeed.off()
                print("Switching to Low!!!")
            lowLed.value(0)
            highLed.value(0)
            offLed.value(0)
            timeLed.value(1)
        html = webpage()
        client.send(html)
        client.close()
try:
    ip = connect()
    connection = open_socket(ip)
    serve(connection)
# here is my code for the override buttons but im not sure where to put it to the code to read them
# it is basically the same as above just not in a function 
# I tried putting the lowButton.value() == 0 part after the requests with an or statment but that didn't work
    if lowButton.value() == 0:
        lowSpeed.on()
        highSpeed.off()
        print("Low Selected!!!")
        lowLed.value(1)
        highLed.value(0)
        offLed.value(0)
        timeLed.value(0)
    if highButton.value() == 0:
        lowSpeed.off()
        highSpeed.on()
        print("High Selected!!!")
        lowLed.value(0)
        highLed.value(1)
        offLed.value(0)
        timeLed.value(0)
    if offButton.value() == 0:
        lowSpeed.off()
        highSpeed.off()
        print("Off Selected!!!")
        lowLed.value(0)
        highLed.value(0)
        offLed.value(1)
        timeLed.value(0)
    if timeButton.value() == 0:
        if utime.localtime()[3] >= highTime or utime.localtime()[3] < lowTime:
            lowSpeed.off()
            highSpeed.on()
            print("Switching to High!!!")
        if utime.localtime()[3] >= lowTime or utime.localtime()[3] < highTime:
            lowSpeed.on()
            highSpeed.off()
            print("Switching to Low!!!")
        lowLed.value(0)
        highLed.value(0)
        offLed.value(0)
        timeLed.value(1)
 # here is where the button code ends
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    machine.reset()
    

